# programming Quadratic equation using functions on fortran 95

Tags: function, fortran, external, formula, quadratic

I am trying to create a program that uses the quadratic formula. However, I want to do it entirely with external functions on fortran 95. My program keeps giving me weird errors regarding "inconsistent types" and etc.

This is what I have so far. If anyone has suggestions on where I could be wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks a lot!

```
   PROGRAM Quad
IMPLICIT NONE

    !Function & variable Declaration
    CHARACTER(1):: response='X'
    INTEGER:: a=0, b=0, c=0, iost=0, disc=0
    INTEGER:: EnterA, EnterB, EnterC, FindDiscriminate
    REAL:: FindUniqueSolution, FindRealSolution1, FindRealSolution2
    REAL:: x=0, x1=0, x2=0

    !Open statement
    OPEN(UNIT=23,FILE = "solutions.txt", ACTION = "WRITE", STATUS="NEW",IOSTAT=iost)
    IF (iost>0) STOP "Problem opening the file!"


    a=EnterA ()
    b=EnterB ()
    c=EnterC ()
    disc=FindDiscriminate (a,b,c)




DO
    PRINT*, "Find the solution(s) for equation of type: Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0"
    PRINT*, "A, B, and C should each be integers in the range -999 to 999!"

    PRINT*, "YOUR EQUATION: ",a,"x^2 +",b,"x +",c,"=0"
    PRINT*, "DISCRIMINATE: ",disc
    WRITE(23,'(1X,A,I3,A,I3,A,I3,A)',IOSTAT=iost),"YOUR EQUATION: ",a,"x^2 +",b,"x +",c,"=0"
    IF (iost>0) STOP "Problem opening the file!"

    IF (disc==0) THEN
        x=FindUniqueSolution (a,b,c,disc)
        PRINT*, "ONE REAL SOLUTION: ",x
        WRITE(23,'(1X,A,T35,F4.1)',IOSTAT=iost),"ONE REAL SOLUTION: ",x
        IF (iost>0) STOP "Problem writing to the file!"
    ELSE IF(disc>0) THEN
        PRINT*, "TWO REAL SOLUTIONS: "
        x1=FindRealSolution1 (a,b,c,disc)
        PRINT*, "REAL SOLUTION 1: ",x1
        x2=FindRealSolution2 (a,b,c,disc)
        PRINT*, "REAL SOLUTION 2: ",x2
        WRITE(23,'(1X,A)',IOSTAT=iost),"TWO REAL SOLUTIONS"
        WRITE(23,'(1X,A,T35,F4.1)',IOSTAT=iost),"REAL SOLUTION 1: ",x1
        WRITE(23,'(1X,A,T35,F4.1)',IOSTAT=iost),"REAL SOLUTION 2: ",x2
        IF (iost>0) STOP "Problem writing to the file!"
    ELSE
        PRINT*, "Your equation is unsolvable (the discriminant is less than 0)."
    END IF

    WRITE (*,'(1X,A)',ADVANCE="NO"),"Do another(y/n)?"
    READ*, response
    IF (response /= "y") EXIT

END DO

    CLOSE(23)



END PROGRAM

!Begin External Functions ----------------------------------------------------------

INTEGER FUNCTION EnterA ()
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER:: a=0

DO
    WRITE (*,'(1X,A)',ADVANCE="NO"),"Enter A: "
    READ*, a
    IF (a <= -999 .AND. a >= 999) EXIT
    PRINT*, "Must be an integer between -999 and 999. TRY AGAIN!"
END DO

EnterA=a

END FUNCTION EnterA

! New External Function ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

INTEGER FUNCTION EnterB ()
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER:: b=0

DO
    WRITE (*,'(1X,A)',ADVANCE="NO"),"Enter B: "
    READ*, b
    IF (b <= -999 .AND. b >= 999) EXIT
    PRINT*, "Must be an integer between -999 and 999. TRY AGAIN!"
END DO

EnterB=b

END FUNCTION EnterB
!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INTEGER FUNCTION EnterC ()
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER:: c=0

DO
    WRITE (*,'(1X,A)',ADVANCE="NO"),"Enter C: "
    READ*, c
    IF (c <= -999 .AND. c >= 999) EXIT
    PRINT*, "Must be an integer between -999 and 999. TRY AGAIN!"
END DO

EnterC=c

END FUNCTION EnterC
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

INTEGER FUNCTION FindDiscriminate(a,b,c)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER:: disc=0

INTEGER, INTENT(IN):: a,b,c

disc=INT(b**2)-(4*a*c)

FindDiscriminate=disc
END FUNCTION FindDiscriminate
!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REAL FUNCTION FindUniqueSolution (a,b,c,disc)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL:: x

REAL, INTENT(IN):: a,b,c,disc

x=REAL(-b)/(2.0*a)

FindUniqueSolution=x
END FUNCTION FindUniqueSolution
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REAL FUNCTION FindRealSolution1 (a,b,c,disc)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL:: x1

REAL, INTENT (IN):: a,b,c,disc

x1=REAL(-b+disc)/(2.0*a)

FindRealSolution1=x1
END FUNCTION FindRealSolution1
!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

REAL FUNCTION FindRealSolution2 (a,b,c,disc)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL:: x2

REAL, INTENT (IN):: a,b,c,disc

x2=REAL(-b-disc)/(2.0*a)

FindRealSolution2=x2
END FUNCTION FindRealSolution2
```

Comment: I've no idea about your inconsistent types but I did notice that you forgot to take the square root of your discriminant.

Comment: "If anyone has suggestions on where I could be wrong, I would greatly appreciate it." - Well, for a start; stop using so many functions. (unless there is a very good reason for it! Is there?)

Comment: It is odd that you are declaring so many variables as integers for a quadratic equation.  Probably somewhere the compiler is highlighting a difference in type between actual and dummy argument.   It would help if you gave specific error messages, including showing which lines were called out by the compiler.

Comment: There's a few odd things here.  Nonetheless, the code as posted compiles correctly for me with gfortran and ifort (although it runs incorrectly; the if test in enterA/b/c is backwards, there doesn't really need to be a separate function for each variable, etc).  Is there a reason why you want the functions to be external, but in the same file -- as opposed to in a CONTAINS statement in the program, or in a module?

Comment: there is also a capital error in your logic: `a <= -999 .AND. a >= 999` if a is in the range -999:999, then it will be false, if a is smaller than -999, false, and if a is larger than 999, also false.  So it will always evaluate to false... (edit: the previous comment seems to already mention this)

Answer (score 2):

In your main program you reference the functions `FindUniqueSolution, FindRealSolution1, and FindRealSolution2`. You pass `a,b,c, and disc` as arguments. These are declared as integers, but inside those functions the corresponding dummy arguments are declared as reals. So, there's your type mismatch.

Comment: As somewhat already suggested, you would probably get a clearer error message if you put the functions into a module and "used" the module in the program.  That would make the interfaces "explicit".  And you wouldn't need to declare the functions in your main program.

Comment: @M. S. B.: I fully agree with putting all functions in a module (or making them internal), but even as is gfortran gave me a crystal clear error message, identifying this problem.